# Luck metric proposal: is it useful?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Let S be set of events {X1,X2,..}. Let Good be a set of events {G1,G2,...}. Let Bad be a set of events such that for every event in Good, the complement of that event is in Bad.

The set S is considered lucky iff Probability(intersection({x|x in S and Good}) < Probability(intersection{x|x in S and Bad}).

For example,
Let winning the lottery on day i be an event in Good.
Let S be {not winning the lottery on day 1, winning the lottery on day 2}. Depending on the probability of winning the lottery, S is lucky or S is not lucky.

..thing is while this definition is simple, a set S being lucky isn't necessarily related to the expected value of the events. I'm debating on scrapping this concept. Is the definition useful for anything?

Comment: In general, random definitions in mathematics are not particularly useful.

Comment: Fair point. I put in an example that might make the definition more applicable as well as fixing a few typos.

Comment: Why write $A/B<1$ instead of just $A<B$?

Comment: I don't see how that makes a difference but if it improves readability, I'll change it.

Comment: @Michael Not about readability, but division by zero.